# Scroll bar showing up in Options Menu

Tags: android, android-icons

I have created a simple options menu. For some odd reason the scroll bar shows up as below[image]

How can I get rid of this ?

The size of the icons are 48*48. If I decrease the size to 44*44 it solves the problem. But I want a 48*48 icon because it shows up big and is easy to see.

Code for building menu

```
  @Override  
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {  

    menu.add("Settings").setIcon(R.drawable.gear);  
    menu.add("User").setIcon(R.drawable.user).;  
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu); 
  }
```

Thanks for your time and input.

Comment: This one is not sure.But have u tried using android's default menu item. android.R.drawable.ic_menu_preferences for settings. If the scrollbar comes still then there is a problem with the menu item. Else I would guess it is the problem with the image chosen for the particular device resolution like mdpi -> 48 * 48, Hdpi 72 * 72 etc. Just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

this is because you set fixed menu height through menu.xml or through java code . set is as wrap_content .

Comment: I've not added any code in the XML. I am building it through JAVA code. How can I set the height through code ? I've updated the question with some code. Could you suggest me a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

After adding divider height to the theme, scroll bar appear in the options menu.

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">@dimen/list_view_divider_height</item> <!--0.5dp-->
    ...
</style>
```

[scroll bar in the options menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQ0QM.png)


I hope this helps someone else to solve the problem.